# Make a string have the number of lines equals to a value of a variable

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a char variable (`si`) as a string if I'm explaining correctly.
Since it is basically an array I wanted to make it have the same lines as a value of a variable (`n`).

Here is the code:

```
int n, i, j;
char si['n'][30];

printf("Introduce the number of teams in the championship\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

for (j = 1; j <=n; j++) {
    printf("Introduce the number of the team and the name separated by a space\n");
    scanf("%d %s", &i, &si[n]);
}

for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
    printf("%s\n", si[n]);
}
```

(The `si['n']` is probably wrong it was tests that I was doing.)

Comment: `char  si['n'][30];` is translated to `char  si[110][30];` where 110 is the ASCII of character `n`, use `char  si[n][30];` without quotes after `scanf("%d", &n);`, this is called a Variable-Length-Array, also, there is no need to use the address of operator (&) with `scanf`, `si` is already (decays into) a pointer when passed.

Comment: You will need to look into `malloc()` in order to dynamically allocate string memory needed per user entered data.

Comment: @Keine the syntax `char si[n][30]` is not valid unless n has been given an explicit value prior to the declaration.

Comment: Something like `scanf("%d", &n); assert(n >0 && n < 10); char  si[n][30];  for (j=0;j<n;j++) { scanf("%29s", &si[j]); ...`

Comment: @Fredk, that's why I said _after scanf_

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code boils down to difference between `n` and `'n'`.

1. `n`
   This is a **literal**. Which when used alone, usually, can be interpreted as a variable name. This can be used as a `lvalue`.
   e.g. `int n`, `n = 20` etc.
2. `'n'`
   This is a **character** from ASCII set which often decays to it's ASCII value. This is used as a `rvalue`.
   e.g. `printf("%d", 'n')` will print `110`, ASCII value of **character** `n`

Now to summarise our understanding see this example `char n = 'n'`
Here first `n` is a literal, a variable which stores a **character** in it. Which happens to be a **character** `'n'`

---

1. So in your code `char  si['n'][30];` should be changed to `char  si[n][30];`
2. To use C variable-length-array you should use `scanf("%d", &n)` before the declaration of array `si`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You must define the `si` array **after** the value of `n` has been read from the user.  `'n'` is a character literal, it has nothing to do with the name of the `n` variable.
- You must check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure the conversion succeeded.
- index values vary from `0` to `n` excluded in C.  The classic idiom for enumerating array members is `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { ... }`
- you cannot read with a single `scanf()` the team number and its name.

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_TEAMS  128  /* reasonable maximum number of teams */

int main(void) {
    int n, i, j;

    printf("Introduce the number of teams in the championship\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0 || n > MAX_TEAMS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid number of teams\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char si[n][30];

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("Introduce the number of the team and the name separated by a space\n");
        if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1 || i < 1 || i > n) {
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid team number\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (scanf(" %29[^\n]", si[i - 1]) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "missing team name\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%d %s\n", j + 1, si[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```